# My custom block not showing header buttons on admin side in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am calling my block from controller but it doesn't display header buttons.I call my controller function with button click and create block using (

```
 $this->loadLayout(); 
     $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_addanswer'));

     $this->renderLayout();.
```

While on addanswer page i simply use the class

```
Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_module_Edit_Tab_Addanswer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{ 
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
// code 
}
}
```

It display data like the attach image[image]

I want to add save or add like buttons but don't know from where i can do that.I added buttons from block or from edit.php but i don't know how i can add buttons from controller or in form direct.Is it possible ? Thanks in advance

Comment: The buttons above a form are rendered by the form_container. http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-admin-form/

Answer (score 0):

You maybe missing

```
class CompanyName_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Addanswer_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'addanswer';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_addanswer';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('addanswer')->__('Save'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('addanswer')->__('Delete'));
    }

.....
```

Take a look @ [Custom Module with Custom Database Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

Comment: Thanks for replay.I know that when I call the page form tabs than all html renders but when I try to load the block from controller than the buttons and header portion not working.I also try your methode but getting same results.